# Xcode4 - different libraries in different schemes

Tags: xcode, configuration, xcode4

I have application APP and library LIB. APP uses LIB. I have 2 versions of LIB: one compiled for "iOS device", and second compiled for iPhone 5.0 Simulator.

Now I want to include this LIB in my APP project. When I set APP scheme to iOS Device, then I need to use LIB for iOS Device, and analogically with iPhone 5.0 Simulator scheme.

Every time when I change APP scheme, I have to delete inproper LIB library and add proper LIB library to my workspace. In my opinion this is very annoying.

Is there any solution to link different libraries depending on scheme (iOS device / Simulator) or configuration (Debug / Release)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two version of the same library, for each architecture, you can use `lipo` on the terminal to put them into one universal library...

```
lipo -output "My_Universal_Binary.a" -create "iOS_Binary.a" "Simulator_Binary.a"
```

Which you can add to your project for both architectures and it will work fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer! But my problem is so common, that it is hard to believe, that i need to use some tricks and third-party tools, to achieve that! In Visual Studio I can just link different set of libraries depending on configuration. I really believe that the same functionality is in XCode4, but cant find it.

Comment: Other than using the 'other linker flags' to manually link your libraries, I think that you are out of luck.

Comment: And this is how you solve this situation in your projects? When your application uses your libraries, then you use 'other linker flags' to link proper library version?

Comment: No, I've never ran into this problem in my projects, all the libraries I use exist for all my architectures.